# connect-flash shows [ ] instead of a message (express)

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, flash-message, connect-flash

```
      ... 
      newArticle.save((err,newArticle)=>{
      if(err){
        req.flash('error','Sorry , an error has occured. Thamk you try again later')
        //when i use console.log(req.flash('error')) it shows normally in the terminal
        return res.redirect('/AddArticle')
      }else{
        req.flash('success','Thank you , your article has been added')
        //when i use console.log(req.flash('success')) it shows normally in the terminal
        return res.redirect('/AddArticle')
      }
    })
}
```

**this is the route fonction:**

```
  router.post('/AddFormArticle',control.FormAddArticle)
```

**this is control FormAddArticle function that i used to render the flash message and the
page:**

```
  exports.FormAddArticle = (req,res)=>{
  res.render('FormArticle',{title : "Ajouter un Article" , success : req.flash('success') , 
  error : req.flash('error') })
```

Comment: i find the solution : this worked by deleting this following line : app.use(session({
   secret: '',
   resave: false,
   saveUninitialized: false,
   > cookie: { secure: true }
}))